# contradiction between c-faq and my compiler

Tags: c, operator-precedence

The [C-faq](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx7c.html) says that the code:

```
int i = 7;
printf("%d\n", i++ * i++);
```

prints 49. Regardless of the order of evaluation, shouldn't it print 56? 
When I ran this code on my Turbo C 3.0 compiler it gave me the output of 56. Why is there a contradiction?

Comment: Do we need a tag for 'order-of-evaluation' so we can track duplicates more easily?

Comment: The C-faq that you linked to doesn't say that.  I suggest that you read it more carefully.  It actually says "theoretically, the above code could end up printing 42, or 8923409342, or 0, or crashing your computer."

Comment: @fahad: The C FAQ says no such thing, and I don't understand how you could read it and come away with the conclusion that it does say that. It says, "it might seem that the code ... would have to print 56 ... But ++ just says that the increment happens later, not that it happens immediately, so this code could print 49 ... the ANSI C Standard does not require compilers to do anything reasonable with [it] at all".

Comment: That's **not** what the C FAQ says. It says: "it might seem that the code `int i = 7; printf("%d\n", i++ * i++);` would have to print 56, because no matter which order the increments happen in, 7*8 is 8*7 is 56. But `++` just says that the increment happens later, not that it happens immediately, **so this code could print 49 (if the compiler chose to perform the multiplication first, and both increments later).** ". Emphasis mine.

Comment: http://www.c-faq.com/expr/evalorder2.html

Comment: That says "Under my compiler, the code ... prints 49". This only contradicts your result if the person asking that question is using the same compiler as you. Evidently they aren't. Furthermore it says, "The behavior of code which contains multiple, ambiguous side effects has always been undefined ... Don't even try to find out how your compiler implements such things". That is *not* a prediction that your compiler will print 49.

Comment: @Steve Jessop:  I'm going to nitpick a bit.  The exact behavior won't necessarily be consistent within the same compiler.  It could vary depending on compiler settings (optimization level might well change this) and compiler versions.  Nor will it necessarily be the same when tried in two separate statements in the same program (the optimizer might treat them differently).

Comment: @David: I agree with all that (of course). I was thinking that the FAQ question supposes the existence of a compiler which does consistently print 49, but "my compiler prints 49" probably means "my compiler printed 49 once", as you say, rather than "my compiler always prints 49", which might be true for some compiler, but to prove it you'd have to understand that compiler's internals. So, OK, even if the the FAQ questioner was using the same compiler as fahad, it's *still* not necessarily a contradiction. "Only if", but not "necessarily if", and so my "evidently they aren't" is wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no contradiction. The question was worded from a user perspective, and if you carefully read the answer, you will find the remark

> The behavior of code which contains
>   multiple, ambiguous side effects has
>   always been undefined.

So it might print 49, or 56. Undefined behavior is, after all, undefined. This is why there is no real contradiction. You might want to brush up your understanding of what are called sequence points.

Comment: Many a times such questions comes in the examinations that what will be the output of the above program,should I write there that it would be UB?

Comment: @fahad: that's up to you and your professor. "Undefined behavior" is **a** correct answer, but they may be looking for more insight into your thought process.

Comment: @fahad:  If such things come up in your exams, you are being taught by people who don't have much knowledge of C.  Try to pass the exams, disregard anything your instructors say that doesn't sound right (it may well be wrong), and get your knowledge from reputable sources, like good books or Stack Overflow high-rated answers.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's **undefined behavior**.  The compiler can do whatever it wants: it can make the code print 56, 49, or "your mom", and the compiler would still be standards-conforming.

You can't modify the same value more than once between two sequence points.

Comment: Makes me want to write a compiler which will print 'Your mom' every time you hit an undefined behaviour :)

Answer (score 3):

The expression `i++ * i++` invokes undefined behavior, so *any* result is possible.

Why is it undefined?  Because the language standard says so:

```
6.5 Expressions
...
2  Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its 
   stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.72) 
   Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value 
   to be stored.73)
...
73) This paragraph renders undefined statement expressions such as

    i = ++i + 1;
    a[i++] = i;

while allowing

    i = i + 1;
    a[i] = i;
```

where "undefined behavior" means

```
3.4.3
1 undefined behavior
  behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of 
  erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements

2 NOTE Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation 
  completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation 
  or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment 
  (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a 
  translation or execution  (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).

3 EXAMPLE An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow.
```

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 2):

Does the C-faq really say that? You're modifying a variable (`i`) twice with an intervening sequence point, which simply gives undefined behavior, nothing more or less. It could print 49 or 56, or 73295, or nothing at all, or "Formatting hard drive..." (and proceed to do exactly that).

Edit: As to what's *likely* to happen, it comes down to this: with a post-increment, the increment part can happen anywhere between the time you retrieve the value, and the next sequence point. The generated code could easily act like this:

```
int temp = i;
++i;
int temp2 = i;
++i;

printf("%d\n", temp * temp2);
```

On the other hand, it could also act like this:

```
int temp = i;
int temp2 = i;
++i;
++i;
printf("%d\n", temp * temp2);
```

While one of these two is likely, the standard doesn't mandate either one. As I said above, it's undefined behavior, which means the C standard doesn't place *any* limitation on what the code could do.

Comment: No, the C-faq doesn't really say that.  Questioner needs to read it more carefully.